# How to load html string which contains double quotes into UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a html string looks like this:

```
<html> <head> <title>some text</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.xyz.com/css/main.mobile.css" /> ...
```

the text itself contains double quotes so how can I load into a NSString because I cannot do this;

```
 NSString *html = @"  "
```

put above html string in the double quote.  My goal is to load the html string into UIVewView.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a string literal, then you just need to escape the double-quotes with backslashes, like this:

```
NSString *html = @"<html> <head> <title>some text</title> <link rel=\"stylesheet\" ...";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put a backslash in front of each quote

```
NSString *test = @"lorem\"ipsum\"do...";
```

or put the HTML in a separated file and load it into the NSString

```
// get a reference to our file
NSString *myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"html"];

// read the contents into a string
NSString *myFile = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// display our file
NSLog("Our file contains this: %@", myFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlStr = [htmlStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```

THen load into webwiew

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to replace all the double quotes in string with single quotes.